# how to copy whole directories using FTP commands

Tags: ftp

Anyone know how to put whole directories from local to another server using FTP command?

i had use mput , but it just transfer file only.

cd /images_temp  --> ws_ftp virtual folder name
mput *.IMG   --> just transfer multiple file

anyone can teach me what command i need to use to transfer whole directories?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use `mput *` or `mget *`. Confirm with `a` rather than `y`. You can change the prompting behavior using the prompt command. You will find more information in the manual page. In a unix environment, `man ftp`

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate and decent into directories and use `mput *.IMG` but that would probably inefficient. Consider using [ncftpput](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-upload-the-files-and-directory-tree-to-remote-ftp-server.html) where you can upload the directory remotely with just one line.